# JSON encode output with symbol "\/" with PHP

Tags: php, json

I new in PHP programming and I try to make simple API with simple PHP. Below my snippet code :

```
$con = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DB);
$sql_results = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `table-images`");
$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_results)) {
  $rows[] = $r;
}
echo'{"response":'.json_encode($rows).'}';
```

The code above have JSON output like below :

```
{"response":[{"id":"31","shirtImage":"Content\/Images\/Short Sleeve\/874be7b82812f76c944d71706c9651eb.gif"},{"id":"32","shirtImage":"Content\/Images\/Short Sleeve\/b-Cleaned.png"}]}
```

I want to know why value of field `shirtImage` have extra symbol `\` . In my database the value is correct example `Content/Images/Short Sleeve/b-Cleaned.png` but when it encode to JSON the output have changed. How to fix this?

I find some keyword regarding my case, but it still does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

json_encode() escapes forward slash. Try using:

```
echo'{"response":'.json_encode($rows, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES).'}';
```

Comment: Glad to know. You can find all the available options here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to fix.

[JSON](http://json.org) is a format that encodes a data structure in a way that makes it storable and transportable. When the data is needed for processing you have to decode it from JSON.

You can use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) in PHP or [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) in JavaScript to restore the original data and work with it.

Many other languages provide a function or library to work with JSON.

You should not generate JSON manually. The correct way to produce a JSON from your data is:

```
$response = ['response' => $rows];
echo json_encode($response);
```

Because the values stored in `$rows` are arrays (and because it is easier to work with arrays in PHP than with bare objects) when you decode the JSON in PHP it's recommended to pass `true` as the second argument to `json_decode()`. This way it uses arrays in the restored data structure.
Otherwise it produces instances of [`stdClass`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php) which are bare PHP objects. The arrays are more versatile.

Comment: Thank you , sorry before I really new in PHP. Its better and clean using `['response' => $rows]`

Answer (score 0):

```
Its due to escaping / with `\` and it will be removed when you decode your json back.
```

Try to decode it back.

```
$d = json_decode('{"response":[{"id":"31","shirtImage":"Content/Images/Short Sleeve/874be7b82812f76c944d71706c9651eb.gif"},{"id":"32","shirtImage":"Content/Images/Short Sleeve/b-Cleaned.png"}]}');

print_r($d);die;  // This will give you the original data with out `\`
```

Comment: Yea I know that I can handle it in Java Android when I decode that JSON. But can `json_encode`s php remove that symbol?

Comment: Yes, It will. Just try it.